# NullPointerException when working with arrays

Tags: java, arrays, string, object, nullpointerexception

I am trying to create a program for an online Java course. This program includes an Employee class and a Name class. I have to create multiple Employee objects and prompt the user to enter the employee's name. I am storing all the Employee objects in an employee array.

Here's the code:

```
    //Creates employee array with the number of array elements being however many          
    //employees there are:
    Employee employee[] = new Employee [ numEmp ];

    for( int j = 0; j < numEmp; j++ )
    {
        System.out.println( "Please enter the first name of employee number "
                + ( j + 1 ) );
        Scanner input2 = new Scanner( System.in );
        String nameF = input2.nextLine();

        //This should set the employee object at employee array element "j" to the          
        //String nameF
        employee[ j ].setFirstName( nameF );
```

The problem is that the compiler, while running the program, says that the last line is a NullPointerException.
I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. Any suggestions?

Thanks! 
-Sean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You created a new array with a size of `numEmp`, but the default value for each element is `null`. This means that the array initially contains `numEmp` null references. You need to use `new` to instantiate each Employee object before you can call methods on them.

You can either do this immediately after you create the array:

```
Employee employee[] = new Employee [ numEmp ];
for( int j = 0; j < numEmp; j++ )
{
    employee[j] = new Employee();
}
```

Or you could do it inside your existing loop, just before you first need to use the object:

```
employee[j] = new Employee();
employee[j].setFirstName(nameF);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That problem is fixed, although now another one has popped up. I'm working on it now.

Answer (score 3):

You're not creating any `Employee` objects. Creating the array doesn't create any `Employee` objects - the array doesn't *contain* objects, it contains *references*, and initially all those references are null. You just need:

```
employee[j] = new Employee();
employee[j].setFirstName(nameF);
```

It's worth being very clear about the differences between objects and references - it affects all aspects of the language, from default values, to the assignment operator, to parameter passing, to garbage collection. It can be particularly confusing if you've come from a C++ background, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

```
 employee[ j ] = new Employee();
employee[ j ].setFirstName( nameF );
```